# SSMS UPSERT Procedure for API call

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm a SQL padawan who knows just how to write queries to get the data I need.

I wrote an API in Python that writes the results of its call into an SSMS database I created.

Now I'm stuck in the fun part to write the command to check if:

- any id *exists* in the database, and
- if *YES*, check if the cleared status has changed, update it, and
- if *NO*, insert the new data

I can roughly understand the logic from what I researched, but have no clue on how to apply it to my needs.

That's the code I came up with to test.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM critical_alerts WHERE id = 'DS24960882')
BEGIN
    UPDATE critical_alerts 
    SET cleared = 0 
    WHERE id = 'DS24960882'
END
```

TIA,
Nelson

Comment: Use the `MERGE` statement in a transaction.

Comment: Suggest you read this discussion of [upsert anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) first and perhaps research what a race condition is.